# Url.Page() does not create a url for default handler with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

For several pages in an application I use the handler mechanism, making use of the `{handler?}` segment in the `@page` route. The pages also have parameters.

When creating a url with `Url.Page(...)`, or when returning a `Redirect(...)`, everything works when a pagehandler is supplied. However, it seems not possible to create a url without pagehandler.

For example: In a new ASP.NET Core Web App, create a razor page with the following body

```
@page "{handler?}/{name?}"
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Things.ViewModel
@{
}

<p>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
</p>

<p>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TestUrl)
</p>
```

and code behind

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages.Things
{
  public class ViewModel : PageModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string TestUrl { get; set; } = "";

    public void OnGet(string? name)
    {
      Name = name ?? "-- none --";

      TestUrl = Url.Page("View", new { name }) ?? "-- no url --";
    }

    public void OnGetYellow(string? name)
    {
      Name = $"Yellow {name ?? "-- noname --"}";

      TestUrl = Url.Page("View", pageHandler: "Yellow", new { name }) ?? "-- no url --";
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following test results:

| Test url | Created url on resulting page |
| --- | --- |
| https://localhost:7066/Things/View/Yellow/test | /Things/View/Yellow/test |
| https://localhost:7066/Things/View/Yellow?name=test | /Things/View/Yellow/test |
| https://localhost:7066/Things/View/Yellow | /Things/View/Yellow |
| https://localhost:7066/Things/View | /Things/View |
| https://localhost:7066/Things/View?name=test | -- no url -- |

So basically it works, except when I want to create a link without pagehandler. Is there a route value I have to add in this case? Is there a special value for the `pageHandler` parameter I have to use? Or is it impossible to generate this kind of url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify multiple optional parameters without providing values for each one. Routing cannot map to an empty URL segments.

Your best solution is to remove the parameters from the route template and let routing pass values in the query string. Then it doesn't matter if one or more are missing.

I did an article on this a few years back: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/339/optional-parameters-in-razor-pages-routing

Comment: How sad. Pitty I missed your article during my search for an answer.

Comment: It seems it works when I remove the parameter from the path. Then the `Url.Page()` function adds it as a url query parameter.